# SQL Like Clause with escape single quote

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, escaping

Hi I am trying to run this query in SQL  but it is not giving me the result :

```
SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Expr1
FROM            restaurantData
WHERE        (restaurantInfo LIKE '''%' + 'xyz' + '%''') OR
                         (restaurantName LIKE '''%' + 'xyz' + '%''') OR
                         (restaurantDescription LIKE '''%' + 'xyz' + '%''')
```

I have restaurantName column with value xyz Restaurant

Here is some sample data

Comment: why not just: LIKE '%Guu%' etc. ?

Comment: Try breaking it into smaller parts and see if each like behaves as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why the extra single-quotes?

```
   SELECT
            COUNT(*) AS Expr1 
    FROM  restaurantData 
    WHERE        (restaurantInfo LIKE '%Guu%') 
OR (restaurantName LIKE '%Guu%') 
    OR (restaurantDescription LIKE '%Guu%')
```

It looks like you're trying to build it dynamically; if that's the case, then I'd suggest you post how you're building it.

Comment: This worked I have never user Like clause before so i was unaware of the syntax

Answer (score 2):

When the string concatenation is performed here's what you are using to compare the results to:

```
'%Guu%'
```

When you put two single quote characters one after another in a SQL string, it is "escaped", so `''` is used as `'`. If your data set includes the quote characters, you will match things like:

```
restaurantInfo 
--------------
'ABCGuuDEF'
'xyzGuuamn'
```

I believe you instead want to do:

```
'%''' + 'Guu' + '''%'
```

Which would match

```
restaurantInfo 
--------------
Asdf'Guu'
'Guu'Asdf
```

Or, if you are just looking for Guu without any quotes, just do

```
'%' + 'Guu' + '%'
```

Which would match

```
restaurantInfo 
--------------
Guu
GuuAbcd
AbcdGuu
Asdf'Guu'
'Guu'Asdf
```

Comment: I am trying to do it on the procedure `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dealData WHERE dealInfo LIKE  '%' + @search_text + '%' OR dealName LIKE '%' + @search_text + '%' OR dealDescription LIKE  '%' + @search_text + '%' GROUP BY dealId)` which doesn't give me what i want so I guess I need  single quotation before and after parameter @search_text

Comment: If you include some sample data from your tables in your question, we may be able to make it clearer.

Comment: So i am not sure how should i add single quotation for my parameter to make it look like Like %'Guu'%

Comment: My first suggestion should work. Just modify it so it includes the parameter: `'%''' + @search_text + '''%'`